# Rename sub-directories and files under it

Tags: bash, shell

I've a directory structure, in which directories and files are incorrectly named and I need names fixed. Directory has subdirectories, and those subdirectories have files only.

Within this tree I need files and subdirectories renamed per following table. For example a directory named `hdm` should be renamed to `hdu`. And a file named `hdm_e_01.png` should be renamed to `hdu_e_01.png` per the conversion table below.

However, please note that this will need to happen in two phases as there is already a directory named `hdu` there which needs to get renamed to `hds` as per the table, plus newly renamed directory `hdu` will need to stay as `hdu` and not change to `hds`. Thus, phase one will need to rename them all to something temporary that is non-conflicting and 2nd phase to eventual name.

```
From To
hda hdx
hde hdw
hdi hdv
hdm hdu
hdq hdt
hdu hds
hdb hdr
hdf hdq
hdj hdp
hdn hdo
hdr hdn
hdv hdm
hdc hdl
hdg hdk
hdk hdj
hdo hdi
hds hdh
hdw hdg
hdd hdf
hdh hde
hdl hdd
hdp hdc
hdt hdb
hdx hda
```

Comment: What defines the mapping between the original and destination filename?

Comment: sounds like a case of super-awk-man to the rescue?

Comment: CAVEAT: If you're not familiar with shell scripting ... beware.  It's entirely too easy to accidentally delete stuff you might care about :(  TWO SUGGESTIONS: 1) if there are few enough files, just consider doing it manually. 2) If you still want to script, COPY everything to a TEMP directory, and experiment with your script in the temp directory first, until you're sure it works.  IMHO...

Comment: Instead of moving `hda` to `hdx`, move `hda` to `hdx1` (note the `1` at the end), similarly for all the directories.  Once done, remove the `1` from directory names.

Comment: @Rowland Shaw, I dont know the relationship; got the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, rename your directories:

```
cd /to/your/root/dir
cp -R hda /some/tmp/dir/hdx
cp -R hde /some/tmp/dir/hdw
cp -R hdi /some/tmp/dir/hdv
...
```

Now rename your files:

```
cd /some/tmp/dir/ 
for d in "$(find . -type d -name 'hd*')" ; do
    cd "${d}"
    for f in *; do
        mv "${f}" "${d}${f:3}"
    done
    cd ..
done
```

Basically it loops through your directories, and based on the directory names it renames the files in there as per your specification, except it does not check which were the 3 characteres that were removed from the start of the filenames.

*So* I'd suggest to add an `echo` in front of the `mv` line, like:

```
        echo mv "${f}" "${d}${f:3}"
```

Then review the output first.

If your satisfied with the results, execute the renaming, then delete the original and move the modified dirs to its place.

Then there are solutions like `mmv`, but not base `bash` standards.

Comment: can i use a switch case to copy (rename) sub-directories and files to temp directory.Can pls provide me a template, i cant find cases with strings as its values.\

Answer (score 0):

I thank you for the interesting problem you gave. Here's my solution for that.

```
#!/bin/bash

TABLE_FILE='file.table'
DIRECTORY='.'
PRETEND=true  ## Set to false to change files.

declare -A RMAP=() FLAGS=() RENAMED=() NEWPATHS=()
declare -a ORDER=()

function check_directory {
    if [[ ! -d $DIRECTORY ]]; then
        echo "Directory does not exist: $DIRECTORY"
        return 1
    fi
    return 0
}

function parse_table_file {
    local -A F=() T=()
    local -i I=0

    if [[ ! -f $TABLE_FILE || ! -r $TABLE_FILE ]]; then
        echo "Table file does not exist or is not readable: $TABLE_FILE"
        return 1
    fi

    while read FROM TO; do
        if [[ -n ${F[FROM]} ]]; then
            echo "We can't have two the same sources: $FROM"
            return 1
        fi

        if [[ -n ${T[TO]} ]]; then
            echo "We can't have two them same replacements: $TO"
            return 1
        fi

        RMAP[$FROM]=$TO ORDER[I++]=$FROM F[$FROM]=. T[$TO]=.
    done < "$TABLE_FILE"
    return 0
}

function rename {
    local FROM=$1 TO=$2

    if [[ ${FLAGS[$FROM]} != R ]]; then
        if [[ ${FLAGS[$TO]} == H ]]; then
            echo "Circular rename point detected: $FROM - $TO"
            return 1
        elif [[ -n ${RMAP[$TO]} ]]; then
            FLAGS[$FROM]=H
            rename "$TO" "${RMAP[$TO]}" || return 1
        fi

        local -a TARGETS=("$DIRECTORY/$FROM"*)
        local NEWNAME NEWPATH

        for TARGET in "${TARGETS[@]}"; do
            NEWNAME=${TO}${TARGET##**"/${FROM}"}
            NEWPATH=${DIRECTORY}/${NEWNAME}

            echo "Renaming $TARGET to $NEWNAME ($NEWPATH)."

            if [[ -n ${NEWPATHS[$NEWPATH]} ]]; then
                echo "$TO has had same file matches as the previous ones: $NEWPATH through pattern ${NEWPATHS[$NEWPATH]}."
                return 1
            fi

            if [[ -e $NEWPATH ]]; then
                if [[ -n ${RENAMED[$NEWPATH]} ]]; then
                    if [[ $PRETEND == false ]]; then
                        echo "Can't rename $TARGET to $NEWNAME ($NEWPATH): file still exists and should have been renamed already with previous set ${RENAMED[$NEWPATH]}."
                        return 1
                    fi
                else
                    echo "Can't rename $TARGET to $NEWNAME ($NEWPATH): file already exists and is not part of the renaming sequence."
                    return 1
                fi
            fi

            if [[ $PRETEND == false ]]; then
                mv "$TARGET" "$NEWPATH" || {
                    echo "Failed to rename $NEWNAME to $NEWPATH."
                    return 1
                }
            fi

            NEWPATHS[$NEWPATH]=$TO
            RENAMED[$TARGET]="$FROM - $TO"
        done

        FLAGS[$FROM]=R
    fi

    return 0
}

function process {
    for FROM in "${ORDER[@]}"; do
        rename "$FROM" "${RMAP[$FROM]}" || return 1
    done
    return 0
}

check_directory && parse_table_file && process
```

The script makes use of recursion for solving and detecting conflicts without needing temporary renaming. It can also pretend renaming to see how things would happen if changes were already being made, and prevent mistakes.

Example I had these files:

```
aaa (D)
aab (D)
aaa.txt (F)
```

Then I had these lines in my table:

```
aaa aab
aab aac
```

This is my output:

```
Renaming ./aab to aac (./aac).
Renaming ./aaa to aab (./aab).
Renaming ./aaa.txt to aab.txt (./aab.txt).
```